# Qu'est-ce qu'un « nom à double particule » ?

Tags: sens, noms-de-famille

Dans un nom de famille, qu'est-ce qu'une « double particule » ?

Contexte: J'ai déniché sur un réseau social un groupe nommé « *J'ai une double particule et un chateau de famille* ».

Très peu de résultats sur Google, seulement [cette « définition »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/particule) pas franchement claire:

> *(Nom) à particule*. Synon. pop. *à rallonge*, *à tiroir*, *qui se dévisse*. Nom à double particule:
>   5. ... l'Enfant-de-Marie qui serait cette année choisie pour réciter le compliment à Monseigneur. −Si c'est Lucile des Aubliaux (on ne pouvait guère hésiter qu'entre les quatre ou cinq *noms* à particule et saveur locale dont s'honorait chaque année le pensionnat)... Malègue, *Augustin*, t.1, 1933, p.110.

Auriez-vous une définition claire, avec quelques exemples et contre-exemples ?

Answer (score 9):

Un nom à particule (ou à charnière) est un nom issu de la noblesse (éventuellement acheté) par exemple : « Valéry Giscard d'Estaing » ou « Dominique Marie François René Galouzeau de Villepin ». 
Un nom à double particule contient deux fois le « de » comme, par exemple : « Philippe Le Jolis de Villiers de Saintignon ».

Je tiens à préciser que ces noms sont les premiers qui me viennent à l'esprit et n'ont aucune connotation politique.

Comment: Tu es tout excusé, ce n'est pas comme si tu avais pris en exemple *Nicolas Sarközy de Nagy-Bocsa* ;-) Bravo en passant pour avoir trouvé un exemple de double particule suffisamment notoire.

Answer (score 2):

Jette un coup d’œil un peu plus haut dans le TLF, point B 2.

> […] 2. Particule onomastique, dite à tort particule nobiliaire ou p.ell., absol., la particule. Préposition faisant partie intégrante d'un nom patronymique qu'elle précède, mais qui n'atteste pas l'authenticité de cette noblesse. La particule «de» en français (v. de<sup>1</sup>C 5 a spéc. β); avoir, porter, prendre la particule; noms de famille noble sans particule. […]

[L’article « de<sup>1</sup>C 5 a *spécialement* β »](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) (pas évident à trouver en parcourant la page, il faut l’avouer — chercher « Charles de Gaulle » aide beaucoup) donne la définition (et plus) :

> de, particule onom., exprime l'appartenance à une classe ou à un milieu social particulier, nobiliaire ou plus rarement bourgeois (p. ex. Charles de Gaulle); autrefois la particule indiquait la possession d'un fief noble, d'un patrimoine seigneurial, de + nom propre patronymique.

Un nom à particule, c’est donc un nom avec un « petit de ». Par exemple « de Rotschild », « Poivre d’Arvor » « de Saxe-Cobourg et Gotha ». En général (mais pas toujours, le d’Arvor de Poivre d’Arvor est un ajout) l’origine de la particule est noble. Les ducs ont tirés leur nom du « duché de Saxe-Cobourg et Gotha ».

Dans le contexte de ton réseau social, rejoindre la page « J’ai une double particule et un château de famille » veut probablement dire « je suis issue d’une bonne famille plutôt aisée » — et se veut ironique.

Comment: La réponse est juste, mais la dernière phrase est quand même sujette à interprétation (en plus d'être un petit peu hors-sujet).

Comment: 1) En quoi la ligne qui précède dans le TLF est-elle une définition de "double particule" et non de "particule" ? 2) Quel est le lien entre "petit de" et ma question ... "petit de" est-il synomyme de particule non-double ? 3) "de Saxe-Cobourg et Gotha" est-il une double particule ? Ce qui contredirait la réponse de M42.

Comment: @RomainVALERI La dernière phrase ne se veut pas vérité absolue, mais justification du « double particule et château de famille ». J’éclaircis un peu ça.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul « De Saxe-Cobourg et Gotha » n’est selon moi pas une double particule, puisque le nom se réfère au « duché de Saxe-Cobourg et Gotha », à dire d’une traite. Encore que cela se discute probablement — après tout, le duché était issu d’un regroupement.